# angular 4 localstorage cached

Tags: angular, local-storage, browser-cache, angular-local-storage

i use

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser')
```

to save my current user data, like token and etc

i have use `localStorage.removeItem('currentUser')` to remove my user data when user is logged out, but when i log in as different user as soon as i log out, my localStorage still keep the last user not the current user

below is my code to set localStorage

```
return this.http.post(environment.api_host + '/login', params.toString(), options)
      .map((response: Response) => {

const user = response.json().returnBody;
    if (user && user.token) {
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
    }
  });
```

and this is log out

```
localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
```

**UPDATE**

below is my code to check my current user token status (i put this on my `NotificationService` which is called in all page)

```
if (error.json().error === 'token_expired') {
      swal('Session expired', 'Please login again !', 'error').then(() => {
        this._authService.logout();
        window.location.reload();
      });
    }
```

and i also use `canActivate` from `Routes`

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
    return false;
}
```

but when i tried to disable my browser cache or refresh my browser cache, it changed

is there way to handle this so i don't need to refresh my browser cache?

Thank you

Comment: You should use sessionStorage

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hi, how is sessionStorage work? is it also store data in browser cache?

Comment: @Sandy, could you provide a sample of the code where you are initially setting these values?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic Hi, i have added the set code and remove

Answer (score 0):

Are you using chrome?  If so they just pushed a fix for a bug that caused your issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765524

So we hit an issue with our version of chrome and in order to get past it we had to do

```
localStorage.setItem('currentUser', '');
localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
```

If we did that it worked.  If we didn't and just used `removeItem` it would clear, but on refresh it would come back.

Comment: Hi Nix, i use chrome to develop and still not try it on another browser.
based on link that you share, chrome v 61 is the one that bugged, is this mean v 60 (or lower) is not bugged?

Comment: Where is your logic that takes them to the login page?

Comment: Hi Nix, i have added my redirect process